# How can I pass configuration to Database class

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have a database class in which i want to pass configuration. I have to keep the "framework" and the Application files separate.
here is my configuration class

```
<?php namespace Fzaffa\System;

class Config {

    private $items = [];

    public function get($name)
    {
        list($file, $key) = $this->parseName($name);
        $this->includeIfNotCached($file);
        $item = $this->parseItemToReturn($key, $file);

        return $item;
    }

    /**
     * @param $file
     */
    private function includeIfNotCached($file)
    {
        if ( ! array_key_exists($file, $this->items))
        {
            $arr = include __DIR__ . '/App/Config/' . $file . '.php';
            $this->items[$file] = $arr;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $name
     * @return array
     */
    private function parseName($name)
    {
        if (strpos($name, '.'))
        {
            list($file, $key) = explode('.', $name);

            return [$file, $key];
        }

        return [$name, null];
    }

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @param $file
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function parseItemToReturn($key, $file)
    {
        if ($key)
        {
            return $this->items[$file][$key];
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->items[$file];
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my Database class

```
<?php namespace Fzaffa\System;

use PDO;

class Database {

    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $dbname = 'mycms';
    private $user = 'homestead';
    private $pass = 'secret';
    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $statement;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ";charset=utf8";
        $options = [
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ];

        try
        {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to instantiate the configuration object in the index.php (where all bootstrapping and routing happens) like so
    $config = new \Fzaffa\system\Config;
and then use the config variables inside classes like $class->get('database.username')

The config file being application specific need to stay separate and inside the /App/ folder.

Is there a way I can do it without an IoC container and without having to pass the config object through all the hierarchy to the model (Where I instantiate the \Fzaffa\Sysyem\Database object)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well if you have ruled out IOC and standard constructor injection, then you are left with either using `global $config` (yuck) or making Config a singleton. I would go with the latter.

Comment: Since it's known singletons and globals (is it?) are bad practices, you are suggesting I build a basic IoC container? I ruled it out to keep everything simple, but if it's the best method I could implement it.

Comment: Bad practices are subjective. Most IOC containers i see in php are used as service locators anyway (which is considered an anti-pattern by many). With php being a share nothing architecture, the benefit of building your entire dependency graph and newing up all those objects in the composition root can be somewhat offset by the fact this must be done **on every page load**, often with most of those objects being useless to the current page lifecyle. Imho singletons are entirely appropriate for config type classes

Comment: So this would be a lecit use case for a singleton?  Thank you,  if you post as an answer i can accept it

Comment: Thanks, but i wont post an answer, because this is really a matter of opinion, not fact. Others would argue differently. Really its down to individual use cases. Out of interest, whats the purpose of this code? Is it for learning purposes, or production?

Comment: It's for learning purposes, if you want you can find the sources here https://github.com/fzaffa/invisiblecms/tree/new-structure but i still have to push the config class

Comment: Ok, i will take a look. I tend to work with 2 very different frameworks, Symphony2, which is very powerfull, but was not simple to learn, and can be quite verbose, and fatfreephp, which is a very pragmatic, simple framework. I enjoy the latter far more, but for any large project involving a team of devs, the rigidity and codebase of symphony shines. I suggest you have a look at both, as each will teach you something.

Comment: I'm learning  lot by reading the source of Laravel a framework based on symfony 2 components which is flexbile and easy enough to be suitable for both big and Small apps.